# What is the new way of adding compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When I initially used the code below in my build.gradle file, it helped me import the authentication.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
```

After adding the below code to my build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
```

Making me to have:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
```

together in my dependency, hence my authentication stopped working, displaying an error message in my MainActivity that I declared it.
`"Cannot resolve symbol FirebaseUser"` since FirebaseUser is what I named my import to be. Please help.

Comment: User latest and same version number from here... https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup   and do let me know if it will not work

Comment: Why are you using different versions of firebase ? Change `auth` version to `9.6.0`

Answer (score 2):

add same Dependencies version..

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
```

Comment: Tried to upvote but keep on having this less than 15 reputation issue